# VBA search for '.' and what is after it

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to perform a rather complicated piece of search on VBA. What I want to look for is for anything in my column that contains a "." (period/full stop) followed by a single digit.

I.e. anything that looks like this xxxx.0xxx, or xx.1.xxx ... etc

Note that the full stop can appear anywhere in the string.

To look for a full stop in string is relatively straightforward, I stick in a `For` loop to go through Column:

```
If InStr(1, String.value, ".") Then
     'do vba code
End If
```

The challenge is to how to isolate and identify the single character that is followed by the full stop.

When I use this formula, I am able to get the full stop and what is next to it.. But just the character next to it:

```
Mid(String.value, InStr(1, String.value, "."), 2)
```

Can you guys please advise what is the best method to proceed?

**Edit**

Sample data and outcome:

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at using regular expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/1255289

Comment: Or why not just `Mid(String.value, InStr(1, String.value, ".") + 1, 1)`

Comment: Change your `Mid` to `Mid(String.Value, Instr(1, String.value, ".") + 1, 1)`

Comment: @miken32 amazing... please put that as answer and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the fastest solution would be to just increase the offset of your `Mid` to move past the period:

```
result = Mid(String.value, InStr(1, String.value, ".") + 1, 1)
```

Then check if `result` is a number.

---

A more powerful option would be to use [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/1255289). Once enabled, you could do something like this:

```
Dim regex As New RegExp

regex.Pattern = "\.([0-9])"
If regex.test(String.value) Then
    theNumber = $1
End If
```